# Tooltip en Option Select Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, tooltip

Necesito poner tooltips en los options de un select mi código es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Initialize Select2 Elements
  $('.select2').select2();

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

<label>Concepto</label>
<select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" id="id_conceptoVal">
<?php
  if(is_array($conceptos))
  {
    foreach($conceptos as $concepto)
    {
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $concepto["id_concepto"]; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="<?php echo $concepto["comentario"]; ?>">
      <?php echo $concepto["concepto"]; ?>
      </option>
<?php
    }
  }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente no hay soporte para que los `<option>` de un Select pueda contener Tooltips, ya que no es compatible con los navegadores. Ni si quiera por medio de Plugins.
Lo mas cercano que puedes tener a un Tooltip, es asignar un `title=""` a las `<options>` que es como el Tooltip, mostrando un mensaje al momento de que pones el Mouse arriba de la opcion.
Seria de la siguiente manera:

```
<option value="<?php echo $concepto["id_concepto"];?>" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $concepto["comentario"];?>"> <?php echo $concepto["concepto"]; ?> </option>
```

Esta informacion la investigue gracias a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag) en la comunidad de StackOverflow en Ingles, si deseas consultar informacion mas detallada, te recomiendo que te des una leida en esa pregunta. Espero haya sido de ayuda.
Saludos!